# C#, overload for single T and for IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, object, methods, overloading, ienumerable

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(T entry) where T : class
{
        //stuff
}

public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(IEnumerable<T> entries) where T : class
{
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        //stuff
    }
```

No matter what I send into this method, the first one is always chosen. How do I separate IEnmuerables and single objects?

```
AddOrUpdate(entry); //goes into first one
AddOrUpdate(new Analog[] { entry}); //still goes into first one
```

Comment: There could be several types of classes, that would mean I'd have to make such overloads for all of them? Does not seem to be very generic

Comment: No, what I showed is the caller.

Comment: Use `AddOrUpdate<IEnumerable<Analog>>(...);` to call. This is generic.

Comment: Unless you pass _explicitly_ an `IEnumerable<T>`, the single-item overload will be preferred. That’s why the framework has lots of `AddRange` methods, to avoid such a conflict.

Comment: Did you try to understand the problem at all? Your first method is always a better match since `T` is inferred to be a `Analog[]` while the second one requires a conversion, hence ranks lower for the compiler to consider.

Comment: There is whole section of the specs written about overload resolution `12.6.4 Overload resolution` moving into more depth `12.6.4.3 Better function member` because your types are different it considered the more generic type better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the definition of the first overload states that the argument of the method is of the same type as its generic argument (both are of type `T`) whenever you call the method without explicitly pointing the generic argument (`AddOrUpdate(new Analog[] { entry })`) the compiler decides that the types match - `AddOrUpdate<Analog[]>(new Analog[] { entry })`.
You need to explicitly point the generic argument in order to help the compiler choose the correct overload:

```
AddOrUpdate<Analog>(new Analog[] { entry });
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you don't want to change the method declarations at all, there are two ways I can think of to make the compiler prefer the second one when you call the method.

- specify the generic parameter:

  ```
  AddOrUpdate<Analog>(new Analog[] { entry });
  ```
- make the argument of the compile time type `IEnumerable<Analog>`:

  ```
  IEnumerable<Analog> x = new Analog[] { entry };
  AddOrUpdate(x);
  // or
  AddOrUpdate(new string[] {""}.AsEnumerable());
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass in explicitly the type of the argument:

```
AddOrUpdate(someEnumerable as IEnumerable<Analog>);
```